# Converting from Cartesian to Spherical matlab?

Tags: matlab, angle

I'm getting confused with the variety of names for angles in Spherical Coordinates. According to Matlab documentation that "azimuth and elevation are angular displacements in radians. azimuth is the counterclockwise angle in the x-y plane measured from the positive x-axis. elevation is the elevation angle from the x-y plane. r is the distance from the origin to a point."

Ok, I will call azimuth angle as Theta and elevation angle as Phi. Now, I want to build a function that convert Cartesian to Spherical. This is what I did

```
function [y] = my_car2sph(x)
    d = sqrt(x(1)^2 + x(2)^2 + x(3)^2);
  Phi = acos(x(3)/d);   % elevation angle 
Theta = atan2(x(2),x(1)); % azimuth
y = [d; Theta; Phi];
```

Now, the output of this function

```
>> my_car2sph([1; 1; 1])

ans =

    1.7321   <--- d
    0.7854   <--- Theta (azimuth)
    0.9553   <--- Phi (elevation)
```

Now, if I use the Matlab's function, this is what I'm getting

```
>> [azimuth,elevation,r] = cart2sph(1,1,1)

azimuth =

    0.7854


elevation =

    0.6155


r =

    1.7321

>>
```

Why the elevation angle (Phi) is not the same?

Comment: Type `edit cart2sph` in your command window to see the code.

Comment: @horchler, +1 for this info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your definition of the angle `Phi` defines it with respect to the vertically up direction, so it varies from 0 to 180 degrees (called Colatitude). Matlab measures that vertical angle from x-y plane, so it varies from -90 to +90 degrees (Latitude). For these sort of applications, I would suggest using degrees not radians to not get confused. 
So if you do `Phi = asin(x(3)/d)`, you get the same result as Matlab.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I have to use radians. What should I do in this case?

Comment: see cosd and sind in Matlab help

Comment: always be careful about sign conventions and reference directions for this kind of stuff. for example, geographers and geologists define azimuth angle clockwise with respect to the N (positive y direction)

Comment: I did what you said and it gave me what Matlab gives me. My question is now is what I did wrong? I have another functions depend on this function, so I want to make sure?

Comment: you did nothing wrong, it is just that your definition of vertical angle was different from Matlab. You were doing `acos(x(3)/d` first. That would return the angle between the vector and positive z-axis (or x(3) axis). So as your x(3) changes from positive to negative, or from (0,0,1) to (0,0,-1) ( or from north pole to south pole), `acos` returns angles from 0 to 180 degrees. Defining `asin(x(3)/d)` returns  complementary angle to the earlier angle, so it is the angle with respect to x-y plane. So from (0,0,1) to (0,0,-1) `asin` returns angles from 90 to -90. see latitude n colatitude in wiki

Comment: complementary angle = 90 - (earlier angle)