# Convert an Array from Spherical to Cartesian Coordinates in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, cartesian-coordinates, spherical-coordinate

I am working in MATLAB with a formula which indexes points on a unit sphere in spherical coordinates.

```
[i, j] = ndgrid(1:N_theta, 1:N_phi);

theta = (i-1)*2*pi/N_theta;

phi = (j)*pi/(N_phi+1);

r = 1;

b = [theta(:).'; phi(:).'; r * ones(1,numel(theta))];
```

Let's assume I choose particular values for `N_theta` and `N_phi` and that each point has a position vector in spherical coordinates, where the first component is `theta`, the second component is `phi` and the third component is `r`. Running the formula then creates an array (I've called it `b`) which takes the position vector for each of the N points and slots them all next to each other to make a 3xN matrix.

I essentially just need to take that array and convert it so it's the same array with the vectors all next to each other but now the position vectors are in Cartesian coordinates (we could call the new array `B`).

I have looked up the `sph2cart` function in MATLAB which is designed for that purpose but I'm not sure if I am using it correctly and am hoping someone could point it what I am doing wrong.  I have tried this, for example

```
B=sph2cart(b(1,:),b(2,:),b(3,:));
```

and

```
B = sph2cart(theta,phi,r);
```

but they both create matrices which are too small, so something is obviously going wrong.

Comment: What is the size of the matrices you get when running sph2cart? Have you double checked the size of your inputs?

Comment: For future visitors, Cartesian to Spherical at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21214098/converting-from-cartesian-to-spherical-matlab?rq=1

Comment: Yes, so for example, if I have 3x4 matrix as input the output I get when I try to do spherical to cartesian is 2 x 2 even though it should be the same size.